# How to stop li tag from stepping down after content addition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on my portfolio site and I've been trying to use li tags to display the different projects. One problem that I noticed is that everytime I add content to the li, it steps down and refuses to stay inline like I want. In the example below, I added "pp" and the first li stepped down. Once the content is removed from the li, it goes back in its original line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.works ul.project_ul {
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li {
      width: 25.3%;
      height: 230px;
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 1%;
      border-radius: 12px;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li:nth-child(1) {
      border: 1px solid #202124;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li:nth-child(3) {
      background-color: #08171f;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="works">
            <ul class="project_ul">
              <li>
                pp
              </li>
              <li>
              </li>
              <li>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want only some of the `<li>'s` to have text?

Comment: all the lis will have content. its not just text. it happens when I add a new element in the li and add text to it. any content added to the li have this problem. but I will be added content to all the lis. I use the first one to show the problem

Comment: Can't you just turn `<ul>` into flex container, with `display: flex` put on it?

Comment: When there is content in all of the `li` items the vertical alignment will sort itself out: they will all line up correctly with each other again, without the extra gap...

Comment: `float:left` on li should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the rule `vertical-align: top;` for your li selector

```css
.works ul.project_ul {
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li {
      width: 25.3%;
      height: 230px;
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 1%;
      border-radius: 12px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li:nth-child(1) {
      border: 1px solid #202124;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .works ul.project_ul li:nth-child(3) {
      background-color: #08171f;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="works">
            <ul class="project_ul">
              <li>
                pp
              </li>
              <li>
              </li>
              <li>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not have enough points to vote up but I'll do it as soon as I can. Thanks again

Comment: got it. I did it. Thanks